# How to quote a modified quote

Tags: quotation

I'd like to modify a quote from a famous author. However I would still like to cite the original author while also making clear that I changed the wording (and adapted the sense) of the quote.

What would be the best / most beautiful way to  do this?

It's not exclusively a latex question, but since I'm working with latex, maybe someone knows a nice example for such a case and how it was solved in latex.

Comment: If you only omit text you could write `[\dots]`. Changes in the wording should be kept to bare minimum, IMHO, e.g., change from singular to plural. This can also be indicated by brackets. For more changes, I would not view this as a quote but as an adaptation.

Comment: So in case of an adaptation, I shouldn't quote the original author anymore?

Comment: You could quote an exact text in a footnote, with short deletions and small necessary alterations indicated by `[\dots]` , while adapting (and saying it) in the main text.

Comment: Hmm it's a quote in front of the book (before the introduction), so I guess it is to ugly to put a footnote there. I basically changed the essence of the quote to a new meaning. I currently go with square brackets around the modification and a "Adaptation of Author X, Booktitle"

Comment: In German you might say "frei nach XYZ" in those cases, which [an online dictionary I just consulted](https://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/frei+nach+Goethe.html) translates into English as "as XYZ didn't say" or "loosely based on XYZ". I have also seen "to paraphrase XYZ" see suggested. But that is hardly a TeX question and probably much more suited for https://writing.stackexchange.com/ or https://academia.stackexchange.com/ depending on your use case. If you want to cite the actual source of the modified citation the TeXnical aspect is just as for any other citation.

Comment: Thanks, that was a very helpful comment. Yes it's hard to keep track of how many "stack forums" there exist today. Still I got qualified answers here. Next time I'll check the forums you mentionend.